# What is a good rule-of-thumb for the size of leaf nodes in a rope?

Tags: data-structures, strings, persistent-data-structure

The formal descriptions of ropes I’ve found use very small numbers like 4 or 8 characters per leaf node as the maximum size. Some also mention that this (obviously) is not a very efficient rope size for use in real life, but makes it easier to see the tree in a demonstrative diagram.

The trade-off is between speed of manipulation and memory/access overhead. What’s the correct size for a rope on a real computer?

Comment: This looks, to me, to be entirely a question about implementation, which I think would be better suited to [so].

Comment: Have you run any benchmarks, or are you interested in theoretical exploration of the correct cut-off resp. the trade-off?

Comment: I don't see how this is going to be answerable with the information provided.  The answer is of course going to depend on the specifics of the particular architecture you are using, and possibly on other factors.  Are you asking *how* one would determine the optimal size for this threshold?  That might be answerable.  What approaches have you considered?